# React: how to select multiple HTML items within the same component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple component with many divs. Some of them have class="sum". How can I select them?

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div></div>
            <div className="sum"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            ...
            <div className="sum"></div>
            <div className="sum"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I know that `document.querySelectorAll` is not an option. If `div.sum` were one or two, I could use `ref`, but in this case I don't know  what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the `div` elements? Asking because there may be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: It's just a sample task. you could have a table or other items. I just want to know how to select multiple items in the same component.

Comment: This might give you a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922301/javascript-how-to-select-elements-within-one-instance-of-a-react-class

Comment: When do you want to select them? After every render?

Comment: Let's say I have a table with multiple ".sum" cells. I'd like to make a total. How to get the values of those cells so I can sum them?

Comment: @Azu it sounds like you’re new to React. You shouldn’t directly access elements unless there’s no other way. In your case, you should use JS code to transform the data model to aggregate the sums then render the result.

Comment: @Distortum, yes, I'm new to React, that's why I'd like to know how to approach different situations. Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are worse ways to solve this than using `querySelectorAll`. Since you haven't said *why* you don't want `querySelectorAll`, I'm going to provide a solution using it.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    // NOTE: Change list deliberately omitted so this runs after
    //       every render is applied to the DOM.
    useEffect(
        () => {
            const sumDivs = ref.current
                ? [...ref.current.querySelectorAll(':scope > .sum')]
                : []

            // TODO: Do something with sumDivs
        }
    )

    return (
        <div ref={ref} className="container">
            <div></div>
            <div className="sum"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            ...
            <div className="sum"></div>
            <div className="sum"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I meant I shouldn't use `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: I was just thinking that was fairly aggressive XD